# Multisite installation, each website should have different IP

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-6

I have 17 sites with a multisite installation and uses the domain access module. This means that I have the same code base and same database for all 17 sites.Is it possible to configure Apache(hosting server) in such a way that all sites have a different IP even if the physical location for all sites is same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, if your server is set up to accept traffic for each IP, you just need to use IP-based `VirtualHost`s instead of name-based `VirtualHost`s.

Namely, you'll need to have Apache `Listen` directive for each IP address in `apache.conf`, and each `VirtualHost` block would have to reference the IP address its listening on.

More info:

- [Creating Name and IP Based Virtual hosts in debian](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/virtualhosts.htm) (it's not really just for Debian)
- [Name-based hosts on more than one IP address (VirtualHost Examples)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#twoips)